# Calculation of CGMA in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda

I am confused with the calculation of CGMA. I know that CGMA = # of operations / # of memory fetches. Firstly, when `x = g_A[idx]`, should I count the write operation to `x` or ignore it because it is stored in register? Likewise, in `z = (x*y) + (y/x) + (y-x);`, should I count read of `x` and `y` as memory reads in the calculation of CGMA? Finally, should I count all the operations in the Kernel function (those five lines)?

```
__global__ void PerformSomeOperations(int* g_A,int* g_B,int* g_C, int Size)
{
    const int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x);
    if(idx < Size)
    {
        int x = g_A[idx];
        int y = g_B[idx];
        int z = 0;
        z = (x*y) + (y/x) + (y-x);
        g_C[idx] = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: reads and writes to registers don't count for GMA.  The 2 reads from `g_A` and `g_B` count.  The write to `g_C` counts.  To get the arithmetic calculation correct, you will need to look at the SASS code, or you can simply estimate from the source or the PTX code.  You should count all the arithmetic operations including those relating to `idx`

Comment: Does `<` operator count as operation?

Comment: Yes.  Any arithmetic performed in the kernel counts (even non-obvious address calculation arithmetic for example).

Comment: @RobertCrovella The CGMA appears to be defined as the number of floating point calculation performed for each access to the global memory within a region of a CUDA program. The `<` operator seems to be disassembled as `ISETP`, namely an integer comparison, so I would say it should not count? The only floating point operations I see are those related to `x/y` in the disassembled code.

Comment: Probably you are correct.  I was thinking of analysis-driven optimization, and attempting to discover whether a kernel is compute bound or memory bound.  In that case, we want to consider all compute operations done in the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like *CGMA* stands for *Compute to Global Memory Access* and is defined as the number 
of floating-point calculations performed for each access to the global memory within a 
region of a CUDA program.

The best way to calculate the ratio will be to run your program in a CUDA profiler and use the performance counters for memory accesses and floating point operations. According to the definition I found, your kernel has a CGMA of zero because it performs integer arithmetic, not floating point. If you change the definition, then `x = g_A[idx]` is one read operation and no write operations. That is because the register file is not stored in global memory (the "G" in CGMA). There are no global memory reads in `z = (x*y) + (y/x) + (y-x);`, so count that as 5 operations. If all threads run with `idx < Size`, then you have 3 global memory accesses and 8 operations. Note, though, that in CUDA, performance of global memory accesses depends on if they are coalesced. Many coalesced memory accesses can run much faster than a few uncoalesced ones. So the CGMA is not necessarily going to give an accurate picture of the performance potential of your kernel.

References:

http://www.greatlakesconsortium.org/events/GPUMulticore/Chapter4-CudaMemoryModel.pdf

http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring12/CSCI-GA.3033-012/lecture6.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The disassembled code corresponding to your kernel (compiled for `compute_20,sm_20`) is the following

```
/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                     
/*0008*/        S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;                        
/*0010*/        S2R R2, SR_TID.X;                            
/*0018*/        IMAD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;              
/*0020*/        ISETP.GE.AND P0, PT, R0, c[0x0][0x2c], PT; 
/*0028*/    @P0 EXIT ;                                     
/*0030*/        SHL R0, R0, 0x2;                           
/*0038*/        IADD R2, R0, c[0x0][0x20];                 
/*0040*/        IADD R3, R0, c[0x0][0x24];                 
/*0048*/        IADD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x28];                 
/*0050*/        LD R2, [R2];                               R2 = x = g_A[idx]
/*0058*/        LD R3, [R3];                               R3 = y = g_B[idx]
/*0060*/        I2I.S32.S32 R5, |R2|;                      
/*0068*/        I2F.F32.U32.RP R4, R5;                     R4 = (float)x 
/*0070*/        MUFU.RCP R4, R4;                           R4 = 1/R4
/*0078*/        IADD32I R4, R4, 0xffffffe;                 
/*0080*/        F2I.FTZ.U32.F32.TRUNC R4, R4;              
/*0088*/        IMUL.U32.U32 R6, R5, R4;                   R6 = x * (1/y)
/*0090*/        I2I.S32.S32 R7, -R6;                       
/*0098*/        I2I.S32.S32 R6, |R3|;                      
/*00a0*/        IMAD.U32.U32.HI R7, R4, R7, R4;            
/*00a8*/        IMUL.U32.U32.HI R4, R7, R6;               
/*00b0*/        LOP.XOR R7, R3, R2;                        
/*00b8*/        IMAD.U32.U32 R6, -R5, R4, R6;              
/*00c0*/        ISETP.GE.AND P1, PT, R7, RZ, PT;           
/*00c8*/        ISETP.LE.U32.AND P0, PT, R5, R6, PT;       
/*00d0*/    @P0 ISUB R6, R6, R5;                           
/*00d8*/    @P0 IADD R4, R4, 0x1;                         
/*00e0*/        ISETP.GE.U32.AND P0, PT, R6, R5, PT;      
/*00e8*/        LOP.PASS_B R6, RZ, ~R2;                    
/*00f0*/        ISUB R5, R3, R2;                           
/*00f8*/    @P0 IADD R4, R4, 0x1;                          
/*0100*/   @!P1 I2I.S32.S32 R4, -R4;                       
/*0108*/        ICMP.EQ R4, R6, R4, R2;                    
/*0110*/        IADD R4, R5, R4;                          
/*0118*/        IMAD R2, R3, R2, R4;                      
/*0120*/        ST [R0], R2;                             
/*0128*/        EXIT ;
```

From the above code, there are the following floating point operations

```
I2F.F32.U32.RP R4, R5;                     Integer to Float conversion
MUFU.RCP R4, R4;                           Multifunction Floating Point Operation (Reciprocal)
F2I.FTZ.U32.F32.TRUNC R4, R4;              Float to Integer conversion
```

Those operations appear to be related to `(x/y)` which is a division between two integers but require conversion to floating point. I'm not really aware of whether the conversions are counted as floating point operations or not. I do not see any other floating point operation within the code.

The global memory operations are the following `3`

```
LD R2, [R2];                               
LD R3, [R3];                              
ST [R0], R2;
```

I would say that `CGMA = 3/3 = 1` for your case (counting the `int2float` and `float2int` conversions as floating point operations).

Comment: Which architecture did you compile for? Interesting that it does not have integer division hardware.

Comment: @RogerDahl Fermi: `compute_20,sm_20`.